# Error while converting a Fully connected layer to Convolutional layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, valueerror

I am using VGG-16 with "imagenet" weights for transfer learning. Instead of fully connected layers, i want to use convolutional layers. Below is the code :

```
IMG_WIDTH = 224
IMG_HEIGHT = 224
N_CHANNELS = 3

model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 
                           N_CHANNELS))

for i in range(4) :
   model.layers.pop()

for layers in model.layers :
   layers.trainable = False

x = Conv2D(32, (7,7), padding = "valid", strides = (1,1), activation="relu", 
           kernel_initializer=he_normal(seed=42), bias_initializer=zeros())(model.layers[-1].output)
x = Conv2D(16, (1,1), padding = "valid", strides = (1,1), activation="relu", 
           kernel_initializer=he_normal(seed=42), bias_initializer=zeros())(x)

final_model = Model(model.input, x)
```

**Last few layers of model architecture :**

[image]

**Error :**
[image]
[image]

What could be the possible reason for this error?

Comment: What type of problem are you trying to solve? Is this model being used for classification or something else?

Comment: The problem is document classification with transfer learning. Dataset is rvl-cdip. There are 16 categories of documents in .tiff file format. I have to use vgg-16 with conv-layers instead of fc-layers